# In the EPR paradox, what was Einstein's argument against God playing dice?

Tags: physics, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

Imagine an experiment as used in formulating the EPR paradox. Say we entangle two electrons and separate them by a great distance. If we measure the z-component of spin, on one of them, sz1, we know the value of the z-component of the other, sz2. If we measure the x-component of the other, sx2, at the same time, we know the value of the x-component of the other, sx1. Which means we can know sx1 and sz1 at the same time. Doesn't this mean that sx1 and sz1 (and sx2 and sz2) have simultaneous precise values? Contradicting the uncertainty principle? Was this Einstein's argument against a dice-playing God? Such a God leaves no room for uncertainty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135487/discussion-on-question-by-felicia-in-the-epr-paradox-what-was-einsteins-argume).

Comment: @Hypnosifl But do mathematical models really exist. I can say they don't really exist.

Comment: AFAIK the only reason Einstein said "God does not play dice" was his profound disgust for the introduction of probabilities in quantum mechanics (disgust shared by many at the time).

Comment: @armand Yes but his disgust was that local hidden variables could explain many (all?) experiments so far. Not just that probability AND nonlocality were needed to replace determinism.

Comment: @JKusin thats merely a reason for not rejecting hidden variables, not for making definitive statements about God. In context it is quite obvious that the Copenhagen interpretation hurt Einstein's philosophy and vision of physics.

Comment: @armand It could also be said a more complicated theory which explained the exact same phenomena as local hidden variables (for experiments at the time) would hurt anyones vision for an understandable science. Simplicity is necessary for science. It could be said he was one of a few that realized LHVs still explained experimental results of the day. That was his concern, unneeded  complexity.

Comment: @JKusin hidden variables are undoubtedly more complexity than probability as it involves more, yet unidentified forces and entities. Einstein et.al. were willing to consider unidentified, hidden variables because it bugged them that one could not be 100% sure of the result of a single experiment. It's exactly the contrary of simplicity and parcimony. The literature is clear about what was Einstein's concern and the context in which he said this quote. Look it up.

Comment: @armand Einstein wrote about fearing non locality which made the scientific enterprise impossible. He strongly believed locality was necessary for science. “It seems hard to sneak a look at God’s cards. But that he plays dice and uses “telepathic” methods is something that I cannot believe for a moment.” He was mistaken that quantum non locality (spook action) makes science impossible, but not irrationally against “randomness” or EPR correlations. Justifiably science must preserve some notion of locality if we are to have success. That was his overall worry. People always cut his quote short.

Comment: Not philosophy, but you have your physics wrong: once you measure sx2 you will have spoiled the measurement of sz1 just as surely as if you had measured sx1.

Comment: @JKusin thanks for confirming his concern was not simplicity or parsimony but indeed a philosophical uneasiness with the Copenhagen interpretation.

Comment: @Charles But if you measure sz1 and at the same time sx2 you know both sz1 and sx1.

Comment: @Felicia That’s not how it works; there’s no scenario where you can learn both values and repeatably measure both to match what you originally measured. It’s not about hitting a single instant in time, it’s that when you measure along z there is no x value anymore — it’s not sensible to talk about x having a value, you’ve wiped it out. You’re measuring around a circle; the two are intertwined.

Comment: @Charles I you measure sz the sx lies somewhere at a cone. The norm of s is known. But if you measure sz1 why can't you measure sx2 at the same time, and by entanglement know the other two. Why, if you measure sz1 can't sx1 get a precise value because of measuring sx2 at the same moment? So sx1 instead of being on the cone gets precise?

Comment: @Felicia I think you’re imagining this scenario: you measure sz1 and sx2 “at the same time”. Then you measure sx1 and can predict what value it will have (since you know sx2), then measure sz1 and can predict its value as well (since you just measured it). But you can’t; your lack of knowledge of the measurement order spoils your ability to predict sx1, while your measurement of sx1 spoils your measurement of sz1.

Comment: @Charles Hi Charles. You I dont measure x1 at all. Well, not directly. But if you measure x2 you know x1 at the same time, because of entanglement. Like you know z2 if you measure z1. So if you measure z1 and x2 you know z1 and x1 (and z2 and x2) at the same time.

Comment: @Felicia I’m trying to explain why you don’t know x1: because your measurement of z2 spoils it.

Comment: @Felicia Please ask at physics.se for a better explanation.

Comment: @Charles If I'm unbanned Ill ask. Im curious!

Comment: @Felicia If you do ask, link the question here!